# How to check if a file exists and loop to ask for new filename again if it doesn't exist?

Tags: java, file, loops

```
public static String getFilename(Scanner getFile) throws FileNotFoundException { 
    System.out.print("\nEnter file name: ");
    String filename = getFile.next();
    File f = new File(filename);
    if (f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(filename + " exists.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(filename + " does not exist.");
        getFilename(getFile);
    }
    return filename;
}
```

This is my current code. It asks me to type some text, then checks if my typed input is a file.
If the file exists, I want it to return the String that the filename is stored as, back to my main method.
If it doesn't exist, I want my method to restart(?). How do I loop it? My current method just re-calls the entire method but if I run this code, any input/filename that doesn't exist as a File will come up as an error.

Comment: What you are doing is a recursion. You might want to use `for` or `while` loops.

Answer (score 4):

```
File f = new File([filename]);
while(!f.exists()) {
    f = new File([newFilename]);
}
// Do what you want to do with the file.
```

This also allows you to directly return the file instead of a filename, but you could return the filename like so:

```
String s = [filename];
File f = new File(s);
while(!f.exists()) {
    s = [newFilename];
    f = new File(s);
}
return s;
```

Keep in mind that this will infinitely loop if you don't ever provide a real file.

Answer (score 2):

A loop is exactly what you need. Inside your method:

```
String fileName = "";
File f = new File(fileName);
while(!f.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    fileName = getFile.next();
    f = new File(fileName);
}
return f;
```

Basically, the code will prompt you for a file until you enter a file name that exists.

Comment: `NullPointerException` thrown at line 3 ... try a do { ... } while(!f.exists()); loop.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
String filename = null;
do{
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    filename = getFile.nextLine();
} while (!new File(filename).exists());
```

after this loop you are sure `filename` refers to file which exists.

Comment: guess I won't hit "Post" on mine